# TableSort - Keep Pagination on table rerender

Tags: visualforce, jquery, tablesorter

I was just wondering how I would go about saving the current page on a table (**jquery TableSort**), on a page refresh?

ie:  user is on page 5 of a table pagination via **TableSort**.  They press a button that invokes a method and requires the table to be rerendered with new values in a certain row.

Currently, it resets back to page 1.  How do I store 'page 5' and tell it to go back to page 5?

Here is a simplified code example:

```
<apex:pageblocktable value="{!x}" id="results" var="c" border="1" styleclass="tablesorter custom-popup">
   <apex:column value="{!c.field1}"/>
   <apex:column value="{!c.field2}"/>
   <apex:column value="{!c.field3}"/>
   <apex:column>
        <apex:outputpanel rerender="{!IF(a = true, true, false)}">
              <apex:outputtext value="something"/>
        </apex:outputpanel>
        <apex:outputpanel rerender="{!IF(a = true, false, true)}">
              <apex:outputtext value="something else" />
        <apex:outputpanel>
   </apex:column>
   <apex:column>
       <apex:commandbutton action = "{!changeSomethingElseValue}" rerender="results"/>
   </apex:column>

</apex:pageblocktable>
```

When the user presses the button, an action happens and one column will now show different data.  I need to rerender the page, but still keep the user on the same pagination Page (ie: if they are on page 5, click on a row, it needs to rerender the table but stay on the same page).

Below is the relevant jquery:

```
<apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.jQueryLibrary, 'jquery.min.js')}"/>  
    <apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.jQueryLibrary, 'jquery-ui.min.js')}"/>
 <apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.jQueryLibrary, '/js/jquery.tablesorter.widgets.js')}"/>
    <apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.jQueryLibrary, '/js/extras/jquery.tablesorter.pager.min.js')}"/>
    <apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.jQueryLibrary, '/js/widgets/widget-columnSelector.min.js')}"/>
    <apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.jQueryLibrary, '/js/widgets/widget-stickyHeaders.min.js')}"/>
    <apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.jQueryLibrary, '/js/widgets/widget-storage.min.js')}"/>

<script type="text/javascript">  
    j$ = jQuery.noConflict();
    j$(document).ready(function () {
sortTable();});

 function sortTable(){

j$("[id$=searchResults]")
        .tablesorter({theme: 'green', widthFixed:true, showProcessing: true, widgets : [ 'columnSelector', 'stickyHeaders'],
                      widgetOptions : {
                          columnSelector_container : j$('#columnSelector'),
                          columnSelector_columns : {
                              0: 'disable', 
                              1: 'disable',
                              2: 'disable',
                              3: 'disable',
                              4: 'disable',
                              10: 'false'
                          },
                          columnSelector_saveColumns: true,
                          columnSelector_layout : '<label><input type="checkbox">{name}</label>',
                          columnSelector_name  : 'data-selector-name',
                          columnSelector_mediaquery: true,
                          columnSelector_mediaqueryName: 'All Columns',
                          columnSelector_mediaqueryState: true,
                          columnSelector_mediaqueryHidden: true,
                          columnSelector_breakpoints : [ '20em', '30em', '40em', '50em', '60em', '70em' ],
                          columnSelector_priority : 'data-priority',
                          columnSelector_cssChecked : 'checked'
                      },
                      headers: {0: {sorter: false, parser:false},  10: {sorter: false},  12: {sorter: false}, 14: {sorter: false}}
                     })
        .bind('pagerChange pagerComplete pagerInitialized pageMoved', function(e, c){
            var msg = '"</span> event triggered, ' + (e.type === 'pagerChange' ? 'going to' : 'now on') +
                ' page <span class="typ">' + (c.page + 1) + '/' + c.totalPages + '</span>';
            j$('#display')
            .append('<li><span class="str">"' + e.type + msg + '</li>')
            .find('li:first').remove();
        })
        .tablesorterPager({container: j$(".pager"), size: 5, fixedHeight:true,savePages:false}); 
}
</script>
```

Comment: Add your code else this question likely to be closed

Comment: When you say rerender - do you mean rerender at the client side or server side? If client side - like you sort the table at client side and re-do the pagination, this is a pure jQuery Table question. If you rerender it at server side (apex controller actionFunction, etc.), all you need to do is store your current page in the client and handle that in the onComplete function of you apex:actionFunction

Comment: Hey Lance - I've updated my code.  It is a pure jQuery table question.  I'm learning, so I apologize for not being clear.

Comment: OK, found an answer - figured it out.  When I'm able to post an answer (after taken off hold), I'll post it for posterity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so I figured this out and learned some very basic JavaScript.

1)  Create a global variable to hold the page number

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
j$ = jQuery.noConflict();
var pagerPage =0;  //Global Variable!
j$(document).ready(function ()
```

2)  Have a method to get the current page of the TableSorter

```
function getPage(){
        pagerPage = j$("[id$=searchResultsTable]")[0].config.pager.page;
        //zero based, need to add 1
        alert( 'current page is ' + (pagerPage + 1) ); //For testing
        }
```

3)  Have a method that will run OnComplete - will re-initialize the tablesort, but then will change page

```
 function goToPage(){
        alert( 'current page is ' + (pagerPage + 1) ); // for testing
        sortTable();  //this re-initializes the table
        j$("[id$=searchResultsTable]").trigger('pageSet',pagerPage+1);  //This tells the table to change page number.  It's zero based, hence the +1)
        }
```

4)  finally, run the getPage(); on the onClick of your button, and the goToPage(); on the oncomplete.

```
    <apex:commandbutton value="Do Something" action="{!myAction}" status="PleaseWait" 
                        onclick="getPage();" oncomplete="goToPage(); return false;"
                        rerender="rerenderSomeStuff" />
```

That's it! :)